# Create and run queries on temporaries SQL tables using Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, temporary

Using Python I'm trying to create temporaries sql tables (oracle), then I want to run queries on these temporarie tables and convert the output to a Pandas DataFrame.

I created a temporary table this way:

```
curs.execute("""CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_customer
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
(select
    c_entity_id id_customer,
    c_gender gender
from CUSTOMERS)""")
```

Then I want to query on it and convert to a Pandas DataFrame:

```
query_test="""select * from temp_customer"""

test_df = pd.read_sql_query(query_test, con)
```

The script keeps running but nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a temporary table at runtime?  That generally doesn't make sense-- temporary tables should be created at installation time when you create all your permanent tables.  Creating temporary tables at runtime doesn't generally work in multi-user applications-- if some other session wants to create the same table, it'll get an error.  If some other session wants to drop the `temp_customer` table, it will succeed and cause your session to fail.